# Ruby on rails - read and evaluate params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a Params hash coming from a form submit that looks like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxx", "animal"=>{"animal_ids"=>["", "14", "9"], "thisaction"=>"register"}, "controller"=>"animals", "action"=>"takeaction"}
```

When submitted to "takeaction" I want to evaluate the value of "thisaction" within the hash and what I have is not working. This is what I have in a test view to see what I have:

```
<p>thisaction: <%= params[:thisaction] %></p>
```

This always just shows me:
thisaction:

No value.

What silly thing am I missing that I need to change to properly evaluate the value of "thisaction"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the `:thisaction` key is not located in the root of the parameter map like you're expecting, it is in a "subhash" called `:animal`. So you will need to access it like so:

```
params[:animal][:thisaction]
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like my mistakes are usually something simple like this!

Comment: @DrewHarris No problem, sometimes the simplest things can stop us up. Good luck.